# No shell prompt in gnome terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, upgrade, gnome-terminal

I was a bit behind and spent yesterday and a lot of bandwidth with three upgrades from 10.10 to 12.04.  Most things seem to work but when, I launch the terminal, a get a new window but there isn't a shell prompt.

I created a new user and that user sees a prompt.  The only difference in the .bashrc files is in HISTCONTROL--no differences in the prompt.

In my original user account, the xterm and uxterm apps work perfectly.  Byobu terminal fails just like the gnome-terminal except there is some kind of status line at the bottom.

Obviously some configuration was messed up in the upgrades. I'm new to Unity and I'm being GUIed to death.  I would appreciate some help on where to look.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if you mean this `>`

When I get that I type a `|` which renders a error and returns me to my cd dir.

Comment: What do you mean by "cd dir"?

Comment: I meant the typical prompt from the shell.  In my case, it is the username@computername:current directory$.  All I had was a blank terminal window.  No matter where I type, nothing appeared. The window did have focus because the title bar changed color when I clicked in it versus another window.